# Append metadata to a file in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, metadata, exif, image-file

I'm building an flutter app and I'm trying to save images with their respective metadata intact.

I'm using a lib that makes possible to read image bytes and read metadata (MultiImagePicker). But when I save the image bytes to a new file, the metadata isn't there. Also, I'm not able to directly copy the Image I require.

I found lots of libraries to read metadata, but none to append/edit metadata.
So, is there a way to edit/append metadata in dart/flutter?

Comment: Do you mean add EXIF data to the image?  (https://pub.dev/packages/exif)  There's nothing like universal "meta data".

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Thanks for your help! 
I'm talking about all metadata, including exif, gps and device information.
I already had a look in this package before. It seems it can read exif but it can't write it to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my null-safe fork of a package I found on Github that allows you to both modify and read Exif data from a file: https://github.com/PhoenixPhighter/exif_flutter.git

Here is a helpful post on using this package: https://github.com/Beakyn/exif_flutter/issues/2

This package will allow you to edit the location, altitude, and date.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31344396)